# Using tui option of GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

I am currently working with NS-2(A network Simulator) and I wanted to use the tui option of gdb such that i can view the course code while debugging. (Just like Visual studio)

As of now the source window is blank when i run "gdb -tui" . However I can see the file when i  do a "list" in gdb, but I am not able to make it go automatically to the file and point to the break location.

Any Ideas how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the gdb-mode in emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure about the GDB TUI, if you're familiar with vi then be sure to check out [CGDB](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/).  It is a TUI front-end to GDB using vi-like key bindings.

To set a break point in CGDB, just hit escape (of course), navigate to the line you want to break on, then hit the space bar!

Answer (score 9):

Did you try the `Ctrl-X A` combination?
It tells gdb to enter/leave the TUI mode.

Comment: But see http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15163 which is a fun gotcha for the vi-inclined.

Answer (score 4):

Run your executable with gdb as:

```
$gdb -tui ./executable_name
```

The source code will appear as soon as you execute the `gdb` command: "run" on the gdb terminal.

It would be better if you put a breakpoint on some line (say: on `main()` function), then execute "run": The Source Code would be visible now.

Answer (score 1):

You can always double check so that the elf-file contains correct data.

Let's say you break your program at some place, and there you will get some reading on the pc (program counter). That value can be cross checked with addr2line (in binutils) so you do have a correct source file.